# What if one has a cat on flight and I am allergic to cats?

Tags: air-travel, pets

What happens if a passenger next to me (even 2-3 rows) has a cat and I am allergic to cats? Do I have to change the seat/flight or do they put the cat/passenger somewhere else?

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, if it's a valid reason and you have a problem occupying a specific seat, then you would be shifted to a different location, subject to availability.

Comment: if nothing is available then?

Comment: And if you are really badly allergic it might well be an upgrade if needed. But they will try a switch with someone else before they upgrade.

Comment: @NRandhawa If nothing is available, then there's at least a chance you'll [have to take another flight](http://www.thisisinsider.com/flying-with-pet-allergies-2017-9) if the allergy is that severe

Comment: @NRandhawa What Zach Lipton, if nothing is available, they will try to upgrade you to another class. If that is not possible, they will try to switch you with someone else. If that fails, you will be given the option to take an alternate flight.